# SQL Insert into 2 tables, passing the new PK from one table as the FK in the other

Tags: sql, optimization

How can I achieve an insert query on 2 tables that will insert the primary key set from one table as a foreign key into the second table.

Here's a quick example of what I'm trying to do, but I'd like this to be **one** query, perhaps a join.

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (col1, col2) VALUES ( val1, val2 )
INSERT INTO Table2 (foreign_key_column) VALUES (parimary_key_from_table1_insert)
```

I'd like this to be one join query.
I've made some attempts but I can't get this to work correctly.

Comment: If the PK is just an int identity, then you can get the SCOPE_IDENTITY() from the first insert and include it in the insert to the FK.  But you can't do it in one query.

Comment: one query != one statement... doh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite what others have answered, this absolutely *is* possible, although it takes 2 queries made consecutively with the same connection (to maintain the session state).

Here's the mysql solution (with executable test code below):

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (col1, col2) VALUES ( val1, val2 );
INSERT INTO Table2 (foreign_key_column) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID());
```

Note: These should be executed using a single connection.

Here's the test code:

```
create table tab1 (id int auto_increment primary key, note text);
create table tab2 (id int auto_increment primary key, tab2_id int references tab1, note text);
insert into tab1 values (null, 'row 1');
insert into tab2 values (null, LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'row 1');
select * from tab1;
select * from tab2;
mysql> select * from tab1;
+----+-------+
| id | note  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | row 1 |
+----+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from tab2;
+----+---------+-------+
| id | tab2_id | note  |
+----+---------+-------+
|  1 |       1 | row 1 |
+----+---------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks, last_insert_id() will do since I can't keep this in one query. :)

Comment: That is not a good solution, because LAST_INSERT_ID() could have updated between the first and second insert, unless you're using some pretty heavy locking, which you don't mention, and which I would strongly advise against for this sort of thing!

Comment: But the statements are executed *as one* - ie a single DB call, a la `db.execute("statement 1; statement 2")`.

Comment: @Flimzy: "The ID that was generated is maintained in the server on a per-connection basis.", http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

Comment: @Bohemian: Even if you send them combined, MySQL will still execute them as two statements.  If MySQL were transactional, they would result in two transactions.  (Good answer btw :))

Comment: Ah, interesting. It's probably worth pointing out that if you have multiple auto-increment values, only one will be represented by that function.

Comment: Side note: Why does the answer say "It _is_ possible with a single query", then show a two-query solution?

Comment: Ie two separate calls, rather than the "multi-query" single call (not all dbs support this), to minimize (eradicate?) the chance of an interleaved insert spoiling the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` result. also to emphasise to the other answer that claims it is not possible that it is possible. mind you, i have defined "one query" as "one db call"

Comment: @Bohemian: As the doc says, the `last_insert_id` is maintained "per connection": which means that no interleaved insert can spoil the `last_insert_id` even if you send the two queries 10 seconds apart.

Comment: No, it is two queries, and two db calls, passed over a single network request.

Comment: If you remove your claim that it's a single query, I will remove my down vote for propagating misinformation.

Comment: If you don't believe me, try this: "DELETE FROM TABLE foo; SELECT SLEEP(30); SELECT * FROM foo;" and in another window, simultaneously do: "INSERT INTO foo ..." and you'll see that the first set of queries _are_ indeed executed separately, and that the INSERT took place during the SLEEP(). They are **clearly** separate queries, and they aren't even wrapped in a transaction automatically.

Comment: It's the same as putting a bunch of queries into a single .sql file and executing them all at once. They are _still_ separate queries.

Comment: Cool. I will adjust to reflect these points. Thanks for the extra info - I learned something! :)

Answer (score 4):

This is *not* possible to do with a single query.

The record in the PK table needs to be inserted before the new PK is known and can be used in the FK table, so at least two queries are required (though normally 3, as you need to retrieve the new PK value for use).

The exact syntax depends on the database being used, which you have not specified.

If you need this set of inserts to be atomic, use transactions.

Comment: Thanks -- this is exactly what I was curious about.

Comment: +1, although it can be made possible with a single query (from a network standpoint--not from an SQL standpoint) by batching your queries in the back end--probably with a stored procedure, which I discuss (along with some other more convoluted options) in my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a few ways to accomplish this.  Probably the most straight forward is to use a stored procedure that accepts as input all the values you need for both tables, then inserts to the first, retrieves the PK, and inserts to the second.

If your DB supports it, you can also tell the first INSERT to return a value:

INSERT INTO table1 ... RETURNING primary_key;

This at least saves the SELECT step that would otherwise be necessary.  If you go with a stored procedure approach, you'll probably want to incorporate this into that stored procedure.

It could also possibly be done with a combination of views and triggers--if supported by your DB. This is probably far messier than it's worth, though.  I believe this could be done in PostgreSQL, but I'd still advise against it.  You'll need a view that contains all of the columns represented by both **table1** and **table2**, then you need an `ON INSERT DO INSTEAD` trigger with three parts--the first part inserts to the new table, the second part retrieves the PK from the first table and updates the NEW result, and the third inserts to the second table. (Note: This view doesn't even have to reference the two literal tables, and would never be used for queries--it only has to contain columns with names/data types that match the real tables)

Of course all of these methods are just complicated ways of getting around the fact that you can't *really* do what you want with a single command.

Answer (score 0):

From your example, if the tuple (col1, col2) can be considered unique, then you could do:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2) VALUES (val1, val2);
INSERT INTO table2 (foreign_key_column) VALUES (SELECT id FROM Table1 WHERE col1 = val1 AND col2 = val2);
```